# Google Maps bounds on minimal zoom

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a simple Google Map that fill the whole page.
Here is a sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Marker Animations</title>
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var stockholm = new google.maps.LatLng(59.32522, 18.07002);
  var map;

  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 0,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: stockholm
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);

   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
      var b = map.getBounds();
      document.getElementById("bounds").innerText = b.getSouthWest().lng() + ", " + b.getNorthEast().lng();
   });

  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">map div</div>
<div id="bounds" style="left: 100px; top: 0px; width: 300px; height: 30px; position: absolute; background-color: #a0a0a0;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

At MINIMUM zoom level, when you can see several world maps, I expect longitude bounds to be -180 - 180, but in real I don't get it. Is my expectation wrong and why?

In real application I have a server-side code that fetches markers from database depending on current map bounds.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking here. Provide specific details on what you are seeing, what you expect to see, and how they are different.

Comment: If you run my sample (I have just changed zoom level to 0), you will see the following longitude values or like: `-159.11748, -164.7424800000001`. I expect to see `-180, 180` as the map is completely visible at this moment.

Comment: The bounds returned is apparently the longitude displayed at the far west and far east of the map div. So if you have a "full world" display and the 180th meridian is not precisely aligned with the left of the div, then you will get something other than -180 and +180 as your bounds. People have had difficulty with this previously:  http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2009  what you seem to want is the "non wrapped" bounds of the map.  I'm not sure how to do that in the Google maps v3 API.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624760/get-non-wrapping-map-bounds-in-google-maps-api-v3

Answer (score 2):

The bounds will report the lat and lng at the bounds of the window - even if the map has wrapped a few times. So what ever the lat,lng of the bottom right of your window will be one point, and the upper left will be the other.

I had this same issue and what I ended up doing was creating a World bounds that was 90, 180 to -90, -180 and then seeing if that fit in the window.

```
var ne = new google.maps.LatLng(90, 180);
var sw = new google.maps.LatLng(-90, -180)
var world = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(ne, sw);
var fetchbounds;
if(map.getBounds().contains(ne) && map.getBounds().contains(sw)){
    fetchBounds = world;
}else{
    fetchBounds = map.getBounds();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work, as LatLngBounds.contains only accepts LatLng objects

Comment: try that... it's checking for the corners now