# Get total degrees latitude/longitude displayed on a Google map when world wraps- Javascript v3 API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am writing some code which clusters markers on a Google map.  The clustering algorithm relies on knowing how many degrees latitude and longitude are currently visible to the user, as I break the map into a grid of `n/map_pixels_width` x `n/map_pixels_height`  squares and need to know how many degrees of lat/lon are in each square to know which square each marker point belongs to.

Under normal circumstances where the map does not wrap this is relatively easy to calculate using `getBounds()` on the Google Map object and doing the calculations to figure out the latitudinal and longitudinal distances between the returned North-East and Sout-West points.  Where I'm running into issues is where the map is zoomed out to the extent that it wraps the entire Earth `> 1` times.  For example, I can zoom out the map so that the entire Earth is "tiled" 5 times over which equates to `360 * 5 = 1800` longitudinal degrees and, but then the call to `getBounds()` no longer provides useful information:

`m.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat()

88.31833020528785

m.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng()

180

m.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat()

-88.5485785544835

m.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng()

-180`

Basically, the longitudes `getBounds()` reports are just the min and max for one whole globe which says nothing about how many times the Earth is repeated.  Although Google Maps doesn't tile the map vertically (it just inserts gray filing space if zoomed out far enough), I have conceptually the same problem -- I need to know how many total degrees of space the vertical area would consume.

*Is there a way to get the total number of visible longitudinal degrees?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9867711/129475) to another question, I found a (hackish) way to solve this.  Basically, the Google Maps [OverlayView](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#OverlayView) class has a `getProjection()` method returning a [MapCanvasProjection](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapCanvasProjection) object, which in turn has a `getWorldWidth()` method which returns the width of the world at the current zoom level in pixels.  So the way to solve the problem then is to:

1. Add a dummy OverlayView to the map that doesn't actually present an overlay.
2. Get the overlay's projection.
3. Get the world width from the projection.
4. Calculate the number of visible longitudinal degrees as `pixel_width_of_map_element / world_width_in_pixels * 360`

It would be better if there were a way to do this without creating a dummy overlay, but this method seems to work.