# Getting proper map boundaries

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use the simple:

```
var ne = gMap.getBounds().getNorthEast(),sw = gMap.getBounds().getSouthWest();
```

to get the lat long of the boundaries of a map

**It works fine when the map is like this:**

[image]

**But when the map is like this:**

[image]

The **North-East** lat long comes as something like `63.821287740550275, -179.73632762500006`. Which creates a problem because this lat long is almost same as the **South-West** resulting in no-area between them.

Is there a way to get the desired values, something like a maximum value if it crosses the line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get non-wrapping map bounds in Google Maps API V3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624760/get-non-wrapping-map-bounds-in-google-maps-api-v3)

Comment: Could you clarify why you need to get the bounds? That could help finding a solution. If it is for displaying markers dynamically, my 2 cents would be: *don't display them until a certain zoom level is reached.*

Comment: I what to have a location based query depending on the bounds.

Comment: What is the query?  Perhaps you just need to make sure the eastern bound longitude is greater than the western bound longitude (by adding 360 until it is).

Comment: @geocodezip the query is to get places whose lat, lng fall in these bounds `p.lat < '.ne.lat.' and p.lng < '.ne.lng.' and p.lat > '.sw.lat.' and p.lng > '.sw.lng`

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to this question: [Get non-wrapping map bounds in Google Maps API V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624760/get-non-wrapping-map-bounds-in-google-maps-api-v3)

You'll see that as you have stated the map obviously wraps on the date line, so that as you zoom out you don't end up with blank areas at the edges and so that you scroll off the edge of china and hit America etc.

If you examine the answers you will see that you need to check for this wrap and go from there. And interesting question that I had never really considered!