# Check on which side a lat,lng is to another lat,lng on the map

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps

I have a map whose South-West and North-East bounds I take and use it to get places between them.

Because of the date-line sometimes the bounds doesn't come as they should as Explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21454466/getting-proper-map-boundaries).

**So I thought of working on:**

> Get which side the North-East lat lng is compared to the South-West,
>   if its on the right side its fine, but if it's on the left, I have to
>   do something.

So to know the side, I calculated the bearing(the angle between the line connecting these SW and NE points and a vertical line). So, if the bearing is between 0-90 its proper or else not.

**But the problem is:**

[image]

> Here the top point qualifies for a North-East with both lat and lng
>   positive: 78.52379, 158.70952

and

> The bottom point qualifies for a South-West with both lat and lng
>   negative: -32.1087, -150.3139

Still the map tries to connect the points in reverse direction(may be tries for least distance) and give the bearing as **342** which I will consider as a improper points and try to reverse 1 of them :(

Looks like this an expected way to calculate the bearing, if so is there a way to solve/achieve what I wanted?

**EDIT:**

```
function _getBearing($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2) {
        //difference in longitudinal coordinates
        $dLon = deg2rad($lon2) - deg2rad($lon1);

        //difference in the phi of latitudinal coordinates
        $dPhi = log(tan(deg2rad($lat2) / 2 + pi() / 4) / tan(deg2rad($lat1) / 2 + pi() / 4));

        //we need to recalculate $dLon if it is greater than pi
        if(abs($dLon) > pi()) {
            if($dLon > 0) {
                $dLon = (2 * pi() - $dLon) * -1;
            }
            else {
                $dLon = 2 * pi() + $dLon;
            }
        }
        //return the angle, normalized
        return (rad2deg(atan2($dLon, $dPhi)) + 360) % 360;
    }
```

Comment: What does your code look like? If you want to know if point2 is west of point1, a bearing of "east" is 0-180, not 0-90 (that is northeast), your example the second point (upper one) is northwest (-18 degrees) of the lower point)

Comment: @geocodezip yeah like I said I want to know if **NE** is in its proper location, which is 0-90 and the top point is not **NW** but **NE** which is `78.52379, 158.70952`